# Find the biggest value in a given list

Tags: python

by using only a **temporary variable, a for loop, and an if** to compare the values-hackinscience.org
Find the biggest value in a given list.

the_list = [
143266561,
1738152473,
312377936,
1027708881,
1495785517,
1858250798,
1693786723,
1871655963,
374455497,
430158267,
]

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
max_in = 0

for val in the_list:
    if val > max_in:
        max_in = val
```

There is the `for`, there is the `if`, `max_in` is somehow a temp var cause it changes over the loop. You get it.

Comment: ok thanks this worked, I know they may way better methods but I'm very new to python and just trying to get my head around  for loops and IFs lol

Answer (score 0):

No need for either of that. Use `max(the_list)`.

Comment: that's not what question ask tho